# Django Admin,trouble setting user.is_active to FALSE(banning) through admin action button

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am looking to ban users from an action button in Django admin by setting *user.is_active = False*, for the selected users.

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name' , 'email')
readonly_fields = ('first_name' , ('last_name') , ('email') , ('username'))
actions = ['ban_users']

#USER BANNING FUNCTION
def ban_users(self, request, queryset):
    user_obj = User.objects.get(username= 'username')
    user_obj.update(is_active = False)
    user_obj.save()

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

I've tried a few ways,and It either ends up banning all the users including super users or gives the error : ***User matching query does not exist.***

Its a simple function I am trying to implement I know,but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need additional query to fetch specific user inside action method. Use `queryset` argument to update all selected users with one DB query:

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name' , 'email')
    readonly_fields = ('first_name' , ('last_name') , ('email') , ('username'))
    actions = ['ban_users']

    #USER BANNING FUNCTION
    def ban_users(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(is_active = False)
```

Also note than [`update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) is queryset method, and it's not working with single instance.